# Incorrect exit status of wrapper script in KSH

Tags: linux, shell, wrapper, ksh, teradata

We have a wrapper script for Teradata TPT utility. The wrapper script is pretty straightforward but the problem is that the exit status of the wrapper is not the same as that of the utility. In many cases, the script returns 0 even if the utility fails. I have saved the exit status in a separate variable because some steps need to be done before exiting but exiting with this variable's value doesn't seem to work. Or is the utility returning status 0 even in case of some failures even if the logs clearly specify some other status?

The worse part is, this behavior is quite random, sometimes the script does fail with the exit status of the utility. I want to be sure if there is some problem with utility's exit status.

The script runs through KSH. The final part of the wrapper script is:

```
tbuild -f $sql.tmp -j ${id}_$JOB >$out 2>&1
ret_code=$?

cd ${TWB_ROOT}/logs
logpath=`ls -t ${TWB_ROOT}/logs/${id}_${JOB}*.out |head -1`
logpath1=${logpath##*/}
logname=${logpath1%-*}

tlogview -l ${logpath} > /edw/$GROUP/tnl/jobs/$JOB/logs/tpt_logs/${logname}.log

###Mainting 3 tpt binary log files
if [ $ret_code -eq 0 ] 
then 
    binout=$TPTLOGDIR/${logname}.dat
    binout1=$TPTLOGDIR/${logname}.dat1
    binout2=$TPTLOGDIR/${logname}.dat2

    [ -f $binout1 ] && mv $binout1 $binout2
    [ -f $binout ]  && mv $binout  $binout1

    mv "$logpath" "/edw/${GROUP}/tnl/jobs/$JOB/logs/tpt_logs/${logname}.dat"
fi

rm -f $sql.tmp
echo ".exit"
exit $ret_code
```

Thanks in advance for the help and suggestions.

Comment: is that code part of a function? if so, which format, `my_fn () { ... } OR function my_fn { ... }` ? And might help if you indicate `uname -a` and results of `echo ${.sh.version}`. Good luck.

Comment: `uname -a` gives `Linux tpls 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
the `echo ${.sh.version}` give a bad substitution error. In fact there is no environment variable `sh`. I'm using KSH, `ksh --version` returns `version sh (AT&T Research) 93s+ 2008-01-31`. Any further suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: and no, this chunk is not a part of any function.

Comment: Does your utility ever return negative exit codes? I have had problems with the shell not being able to handle these very well in the past...

Comment: @KernowBunney there is no such thing as a negative exit code. Errorlevels are unsigned 8-bit numbers, i.e. ranging from 0 to 255. I know that GNU bash allows you to “exit -1” but that's an extension, illegal in POSIX (especially because you'd need “exit -- -1”), and will just wrap around and do an “exit 255”. Also, the errorlevel is taken using `$?` which will always have a correct number [0;255].

Comment: @xenodevil is tbuild a function? Is tlogview a function? Do you run with “set -e” intermittently, or, worse, “set -u”? Try running the script with “ksh -x scriptname” until it fails, capturing the output, diffing it against output from when it did not fail. Also, when asked to `echo ${.sh.version}` it was meant to type that in the `ksh` you run the script as, not your interactive shell. (But doesn't matter, ksh93s+ is good enough an indication IME.)

Comment: @mirabilos `tbuild` and `tlogview` are 2 Teradata utilities. The shell script is actually a wrapper over the `tbuild` utility which is Teradata Parallel Transporter and `tlogview` is the utility to read the binary logs generated by `tbuild`. They are not functions in the script.
The script works fine most of the time. The incorrect behavior was observed in the production scenarios where it happens like once in a week after thousands of executions of scores of different `tbuild` jobs.
As mentioned in the original Question, I just want to be sure it is `tbuild`, not this wrapper, which is faulty

Comment: In that case, just put a `logger -t mydebugging "tbuild exited with $ret_code"` after the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was in the utility itself, as suspected. Shell script worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The script looks ok, and should indeed return the same exit code as the `tbuild` utility.

It comes down to knowledge of the specific product.

I've never worked with any of these products, but Teradata has an ample User Guide for the Parallel Transporter, with an explicit [Post-Job Considerations](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035_2445_071A/2445ch10.117.01.html) section, warning:

> Even if the job completed successfully, action may still be required based on error and warning information in the job logs and error tables.

So technically, a job might complete, but results may vary from time to time.

I guess you have to define your own policies and scan the logfiles for patterns of warnings and error messages, and then generate your own exit codes for semantic failures.  Tools like `logstash` or `splunk` might come in handy.

---

BTW, you might consider using `logrotate` for rotating the `$TPTLOGDIR/${logname}.dat` files.

Comment: Thank you Henk Langeveld! The issue was in the utility itself, it was fixed by the development team in the next product update. The warning you specified from the documentation related to another feature of Teradata specific to load/unload utilities (discarded rows go into an error table for uniqueness violation or another error table for data conversion issues).

Comment: Also, thanks for the `logrotate` tip. That looks like a useful tool.

Comment: @xenodevil Good. So it was a bug in `tbuild`. Add an answer of your own and accept that, so that people know how this was resolved.